# Direct uploads with active storage mirror service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

According to: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/36312, the mirroring service should be delegating the methods required for direct_uploads to the primary, however, I looked in the master branch for rails (I'm running 6.0.1) and could not find that commit. Did it get removed in favor of something else? The error I get is when active_storage tries to invoke the **url_for_direct_upload** method on the mirror service and it is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the last commit date for that file for version 6.0.1 is 2019/02/14. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.0.1/activestorage/lib/active_storage/service/mirror_service.rb

That pull request you linked is from May 22, I guess that file is freezed and maybe it will be included on later rails versions. (It's still not updated for tags 6.0.2rc nor branch 6.0.2).

So, I don't think it was removed, it looks like it's not part of the code of any release yet.